# UIActivityIndicator set color crashes on older iOS versions

Tags: ios, crash, uiactivityindicatorview

I insert an UIActivityIndicator on my loading screen.
When I changed the color to black color it all work fine on devices with iOS 6.0 version however its crash on devices with older versions.
here is my code:

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 275, 30, 30)];
[indicator setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];//in this line i get crash.
[indicator startAnimating];
[self addSubview:indicator];
```

can someone tell me how can i fix this issue?

Thanks a lot,

Elad.

Comment: The color property is available starting in iOS 5. Which iOS version are you experiencing the crash, and what is the stack trace of this crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIActivityIndicatorView` only supports changing the color on iOS 5.0 and above.

You can test whether the `UIActivityIndicatorView` supports changing the color using `respondsToSelector:`.

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 275, 30, 30)];

// Check if indicator supports changing the color
if ([indicator respondsToSelector:@selector(setColor:)]) {
    [indicator setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}

[indicator startAnimating];  
[self addSubview:indicator];
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html), the `color` property of `UIActivityIndicatorView` is only available from iOS5. You could always do a check and skip it on older iOS versions, if the result is acceptable?